# Is it possible for classes to work together in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

I have this large class that I want to separate into different classes. The reason why it was large because the class had many private variables and functions that are needed to run the program. I was tired of scrolling down the 1000+ lines of code trying to add or edit code. I am wondering if it is possible for the classes to interact with one base class that includes all the private/protected variables it needed to operate, or simply have them as global variables.

I am aware of inheritance as I tried having the separate classes be derived from the base class, by doing something similar to this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    void sayPrivateVar() {
        std::cout << privateVar;
    }
protected:
    std::string privateVar = "I am a protected variable!";
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void manip() {
        base->privateVar = "That was updated from a derived class";
    }
private:
    Base* base;
};

int main() {
    Base base;
    Derived derived;
    derived.manip();
    base.sayPrivateVar();

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Without creating another object inside a class.

Comment: _"Is it possible for classes to work together in C++"_ Yes, that's the core concept of OOP. _"I am wondering if it is possible for the classes to interact with one base class that includes all the private/protected variables it needed to operate, or simply have them as global variables."_ It's possible but you should avoid god classes or global variables.

Comment: You have to split your classes to represent most "natural" representation of "something" you want to model. >1000 loc seems to be simply broken design. Splitting classes only for overview is the wrong way of design software

Comment: Your body text doesn't ask a question, and the one in the title seems too vague to be usefully answered. I vote to close as unclear/incomplete.

Comment: > Your body text doesn't ask a question, and the one in the title seems too vague to be usefully answered. I vote to close as unclear/incomplete.

> I am wondering if it is possible for the classes to interact with one base class that includes all the private/protected variables it needed to operate, or simply have them as global variables

Comment: You are using both composition (by having a member variable of `Base*` type) and inheritance (by inheriting `Base`). Do you really want both?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your class and what you have in it. It is often better not have inheritance because derived classes may then get member variables that they don't need. There are a few other ways you can do. One way would be to group you private variables in different classes and then have member variables in the first class.
E.g.

```
class X {
  int x;
  int y;
  int angle;
  ...
};
```

becomes

```
class XYVector;
class X {
  XYVector v;
};

class XYVector
{
  int x; 
  int y;
  int angle;
};
```

You can continue in this direction and instead of making them concrete class like XYVector above have them as interfaces : to have it more elaborate and flexible check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

At any rate: avoid having globally declared variables.

Answer (score -1):

This is a good question and the answer is absolutely. Inheritance is actually a very good solution in this particular context since that is how object code shares it's scope with other classes. One important thing to note here is that how you call your derived class is important because the inherited scope is set along with the derived class (i.e. declaring it public base would inherit the public and protected methods as opposed to declaring it private which would give the derived class even more access!)

Comment: It seems you don't understand how access specifiers on inheritance works. The derived class always gets the ability to use all `public` or `protected` members of its base; the access specifier on the inheritance only affects what _users of the derived class_ see. It's exactly analogous to declaring a member of that type instead of a base: the access specifier determines what users outside the class can do with the member (or in the case of inheritance, the base's members), not the derived class.

Comment: This comment is addressing the particular context as such the theoretical significance of the general scope is inconsequential.

Comment: Stringing a bunch of polysyllabic words together doesn't render your point correct... that what you said about 'private inheritance giving the derived class even more access' is plainly false.

Comment: You do understand that inheritance gives you access to a parent class, don't you? If not most of this would not make sense.

Comment: Implying I'm ignorant about inheritance is a poor tactic to detract from how you refuse to refute what I've said by defending your claim - that whether the derived class inherits the base class with `public` or `private` specifier affects which members of said base it can access - a claim that isn't defensible because it's plainly false. I shan't participate in this embarrassing rhetorical dance any longer as it should be obvious to others you're wrong.

Comment: Whether thou hast proclaimeth ignorance or not is irrelevant to the clause discusseth.